# Can injected JS redirect a download-on-click file to a predefined filepath?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to write a Chrome extension that, when clicking a button, would download a file that you'd normally get from another button on the existing site, but instead download it to a user defined file path automatically. What I have so far only calls click() on the button the file would come from. I need that file to instead be downloaded to an in memory filepath. Thanks!

popup.js:

```
extensionBtn.onclick = function(element) {
    chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(
      tabs[0].id,
      {file: "content_script.js"});
    });
};
```

content_script.js:

```
function clickGpxDownload() {
    //Where I'd want the file to instead be downloaded to
    var filePath = "C:/foo/bar"

    //Button the file comes from
    var gpxDownload = document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentBody_btnGPXDL");

    gpxDownload.click();
}

clickGpxDownload();
```

Comment: @Kaiido Great, thanks for the pointer. I guess my main disconnect now is how to get the file that would be downloaded from gpxDownload.click() and to work with that.

Comment: Clicking on the button just triggers some JavaScript on the target page. You can't really change what that code does.

Comment: @Barmar I know, but I'm wondering if I can capture the output from it to use myself.

Comment: There are different ways to do downloads, so the details depend on the specific method that the page uses.

Comment: So you need to post the code used on the target page.

Comment: Disregard the above links for chrome apps as you can't use them in this scenario. Extensions can suggest a path within that directory via chrome.downloads API, but can't download to a path outside of the default downloads directory automatically. The user can chose it manually in the Save As dialog, of course. You can also write a separate utility that's installed separately in OS and does all that, see [nativeMessaging API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging).